# How to add background image to bottom tab navigator in react-navigation v5

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v5

How can I add background image to whole bottom tab navigation instead of plain background color in react navigation v5.

For Example in below image, I want to add full width background image instead of plain blue color.

[image]

Comment: can you show example?

Answer (score 0):

> In the Jsx file

```
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
          <div class="logo-image">
                <img src="image" class="img-fluid">
          </div>
    </a>
```

> In css file

```
.logo-image{
    width: 46px;
    height: 46px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: -6px;
}
```